# stuck on /email/verify in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

No idea what really happen, I started noticing the issue when I modified the `register.blade.php` I added a couple functionalities to be triggered together with the user registration.

just to show you the codes on `RegisterController`,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Referral;
use App\CollectorMember;
use App\HasRoles;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');       
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $referral = '';
        $keyword = $request->get('search');
        $referral = Referral::where([
                         ['code', $keyword],
                         ['status', 0]
                         ])->first();        

        if (is_null($keyword))
            return view ( 'Auth.register');
        elseif ($referral)
            return view ( 'Auth.register', compact('referral', $referral))
                                    ->withDetails ( $referral )
                                    ->withQuery ( $keyword );
        else 
            return view ( 'Auth.register')->withMessage ( 'The code you provided is not EXISTING or not AVAILABLE.' );
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    } 

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $user_id = $user->id;

        Referral::find($data['referral_id'])->update ([
            'status'    => 1,
            'date_used' => $data['referral_date_used']
        ]);

        CollectorMember::create ([
            'collector_id' => $data['referral_generate_by'],
            'borrower_id'  => $user_id,
            'referral_id'  => $data['referral_id'],
        ]);
        return $user;
    }
}
```

other than that and the `register.blade`, I did not change anything. Then after I test it that's the time I notice the issue. I am verifying the `email` after registration, so what being happen is, after the user register, the page will `redirect` to `/email/verify`. The issues is the verify page, it just keep on reloading.

How can I solve this issue? thanks in advance!

Comment: Might there be any invisible validation errors on the verify page? If so, can you try [displaying](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) them?

Comment: ho @JorisJ1 thanks for taking time to comment! please my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out! due to my laziness, I made a mistake which took almost two days for me to figure it out.

I modify the LAYOUTS.AUTH to something like this,

[image]

And so I thought it would also be great if I apply it on `verify.blade.php` and that's the issues begin. I change the verify blade from

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
</div>
@endsection
```

to

```
@extends('layouts.auth')
@section('auth')
<div class="container">
</div>
@endsection
```

and sure enough the verify page become like this

[image]

After seeing that i proceed to the other part of the program until I notice it yesterday...

Actually I am thinking to just delete this question because I feel stupid of my laziness but If you happen to stuck also in this situation and you accidentally change also the

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
```

into

```
@extends('layouts.auth')
@section('auth')
```

of `verify.blade.php` then this is for you. just save it back to

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
```

and you're good to go.

I don't know the explanation was because I am just a newbie here. If you have the explanation, please share it to us, we will surely take note of that. :) cheers!